# How to Using an Angular JS controller twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-mobile, angularjs-controller, intel-xdk

I need your help to understand what is happening here. Take a look:

I am creating an hibrib mobile app in intel xdk using AngularJS + JQuery Mobile. I am using a feed controller which have a list of objects (items) and the active object (actual). I am using the same controller in two JQuery Mobile divs with date-role="page". The first one, the feed list, set the actual value (the value for actual variable), in `exibirAtual` method, called when someone clicks in an item on the feed list, after set the variable another page is called, in this page I will show details about this feed item. When accessing `{{feed.atual.titulo}}` and other members of `{{feed.atual}}` in the details page I see any of then are defined, it is, `{{feed.atual.titulo}}` give me a blank value.

```
    afleinApp.controller('feedController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        var feed = this;
        this.atual = itemFeedExterno;
        feed.itens = []; //[{titulo : "1", descricao: "Lorem Ipsum 2"}, {titulo : "2", descricao: "Lorem Ipsum 2"}, {titulo : "3", descricao: "Lorem Ipsum 3"}];*

        this.coletarDados = function(){
            console.log("inicializando o feed");
            $http({
                 method: 'POST'
                ,url: _URL + "coletarFeedDeUsuario"
                ,data: "username=" + usuarioExterno.nomeDeUsuario//usuarioExportacao.nomeDeUsuario,
                ,headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })
            .success(function(data, status){
                console.log("sucesso ao coletar");
                if(data.status == "erro" ){
                    chamarErro("Houve problemas ao carregar os dados de feed");
                } else if(data.status == "ok"){
                    ///Se teve sucesso, verifica se a lsita é vazia
                    if(data.dado.length == 0){
                        chamarInfo("Não foram encontrados dados de feed");
                    } else {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.dado));
                        feed.itens = data.dado;
                    }
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
                console.log("Houve um erro");
                feed.itens = [{titulo: "Houve um erro", descricao: "Não conseguimos recuperar o feed"}];
            });
        };

        /// Called when user clicks an item to show details
        this.exibirAtual = function(item){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(feed.atual));

            feed.atual = item;
            $.mobile.changePage("#feedUnico");
            /// Next line is to test if object value is passed correctly, and it is
            console.log(JSON.stringify(feed.atual));
        };

    }]);
```

The two Jquery mobile pages are these:
The feed list page:

```
`
    <div id="feed" data-role="page" ng-controller="feedController as feed" ng-init="feed.coletarDados()">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" title="{{idioma.dados.voltar}}"></a>
            <h1 class="mission cabecalho">{{idioma.dados.titulo}}</h1>
            <a href="#" data-icon="refresh" title="Recarregar" ng-click="feed.coletarDados()"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="bloco-margem">
            <feed-item-evento ng-repeat="item in feed.itens" />
        </div>

        <div class="bloco-margem"></div>

    </div>
`
```

The directive: `feed-item-evento` is this:

```
<div class="collapse-card" ng-init="visivel='bodyOculto'">
    <div class="title">

        <small
            ng-click="visivel = (visivel == 'bodyActive') ? 'bodyOculto' : 'bodyActive'" >
            {{item.titulo}}
        </small>
    </div>
    <div class="body" ng-class="visivel" ng-click="feed.exibirAtual(item)">
        <span>
            <img class="icone" ng-src="{{item.imagem}}">
        </span>
        <br/>
        {{item.descricao | limitTo : 144 : 0}}...
    </div>
</div>
```

In this element, when you click body you are calling `feed.exibirAtual` method in the element showed by this directive on the ng-repeat loop.

The page who shows details is that:

```
<div id="feedUnico" data-role="page" ng-controller="feedController as feed" ng-init="feed.depurar()">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" title="{{idioma.dados.voltar}}"></a>
        <h1 class="mission cabecalho">{{idioma.dados.titulo}}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tituloFeedAtual">
        {{feed.atual.titulo}}
    </div>

    <div class="bloco-margem painel-tracejado">
        Aqui entrarão as imagens
    </div>

    <div class="bloco-margem painel-tracejado">
        <span class="dataTitulo">De: </span>
        <span class="data">{{feed.atual.dataInicial}}</span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="dataTitulo">Até: </span>
        <span class="data">{{feed.atual.dataFinal}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="bloco-margem painel-tracejado">
        {{feed.atual.descricao}}
    </div>
</div>
```

There is another controller, idioma, but it is working fine. The `feedUnico`page shows nothing. Anybody has any idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a service that will share the info between the two. I'm on my phone so it's hard to get the code in front of me be essentially something like:

```
var something;
return {
    get: function() { 
          return something;
     },
     set: function(data) { 
          something = data;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the solution but I solved the problem. When using a controller in two separate DOM scopes they can't share the same module information, so, once I am calling twice it will be impossible to share variables between the two instances.

More information here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/SQcWaMqsZZs

Comment: The preferred way to do this is with a Service.  These are singletons that you can inject into your controller to share data and behaviors that would be considered cross cutting concerns. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services